# MYSQL convert milliseconds to only MM:SS

Tags: mysql

Hello I have this code:

```
 SELECT name, artists, RIGHT(release_date, 4) AS year, popularity, sec_to_time(floor(duration_ms/1000)) as time
FROM lt.ltdataset
WHERE RIGHT(release_date, 4) > 2020 AND danceability > 0.5
```

But in result I get HH:MM:SS time format. I need only MM:SS

BTW time in table is milliseconds

Comment: @Evert I need in one column MM:SS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use substring for thaT

i am guessing that  release_date is a datetime so that YEAR should work

```
 SELECT name, artists, YEAR(release_date) AS year, popularity, SUBSTRING(sec_to_time(floor(duration_ms/1000)), 4, 5) as time
FROM lt.ltdataset
WHERE YEAR(release_date) > 2020 AND danceability > 0.5
```

Comment: Yes its works fine. Release_date are TEXT type because some data are DD-MM-YYYY and some only YYYY so I use RIGHT function, to show only YYYY